# How to know the form is being submitted or rendered in model page of set/get method of symfony?

Tags: symfony, model-view-controller, frameworks

I am working on symfony, need to know how can we get the isSubmitted() or similar kind of method in model file which can say like form is submitting/rendering.

Comment: Why should you need it? Look first at http://symfony.com/doc/2.3/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html#model-and-view-transformers

Answer (score 0):

All form-related tasks should be done into controller. If you want to migrate some code (legit) I suggest not to migrate "form posting status" elsewhere. What you can do is

- check for form submission
- pass a flag to your model